# Regex for splitting after 2 specific combinations

Tags: c#, regex

I have to split a string of numbers that can look like this: -3-5, 4-5, -2--4, 4--6. Basically I need to split always by the "-" after the first numeric character.

Comment: Could you please specify the language?

Comment: the language is C#, but I tested in Notepad++ which was not a good idea

Comment: You do know the aim of SO is to help you understand what is wrong with your code, not do it for you? You should have a look at lookaheads, something like `(?<=\d)-`. I put this only as a comment as it would require some explanation, but it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression: `(?<=\d)-` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/gS8fR4/1))

```
String numbers = "-3-5, 4-5, -2--4, 4--6";
    for(String number : numbers.split("(?<=\\d)-"))
        System.out.println(number);
```

Yields

```
-3
5, 4
5, -2
-4, 4
-6
```

I guess you would probably then need to split by `,` to get the individual numbers.

Comment: Actually I delimited the separate string samples, so no need to split by ",", but thanks a lot that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $string = '-3-5, 4-5, -2--4, 4--6';

my %extract = ( $string =~  m/([-\d]+)-([-\d]+)/g );

print Dumper \%extract;
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4-' => '6',
          '-2-' => '4',
          '-3' => '5',
          '4' => '5'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\d)-(?=-|\d)
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/14